# ASP.NET TargetFramework attribute isn't recognized

Tags: asp.net

I have been trying to make a project, but in web.config, it keeps giving me the error that it doesn't recognize the attribute TargetFramework.

EDIT: Added the web.config. I have seen one question with the same problem and they said there that it should be the same version as the version of ASP.NET. But i don't really see how to do that.

P.S. i can't change to a different version of Visual Studio (i use that program) since it won't allow me to run the files on local web. But that's a different problem.

Been a while now. Guess it's a tough problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
machine.config.comments usually located in 
\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config  
-->
<configuration>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>



            </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>        </system.web>
<system.codedom>
</system.codedom>
<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the portion of your config file which has this line?

Comment: Wrong asp.net version - you probably use some attribute that is not for the asp.net version that you run.

Answer (score 3):

This happens basically when you have an attribute of targetFramework="4.0" in the web.config but the App Pool is set to run ASP.NET 2.0. The targetFramework attribute is entirely unrecognized by ASP.NET 2.0 -This means it will not work even if you changed it to 2.0 in config file.

If your application is coded in 4.0 then the AppPool is need to be set up to 4.0
In IIS >  Right click on WebSite > Properties > ASP.NET > Version > "Should read 4.0.21006" not 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error when trying to use Fortify with Visual Studio. The Visual Studio Fortify plugin seems to want to use the aspnet_compiler instead of msbuild. It was throwing that exact message.

When I used the command line tools to have Fortify compile using msbuild, it worked. Perhaps your Visual Studio is not using msbuild? You may want to try converting it to a web application if it's not already. I think then Visual Studio will use MSBuild by default. Not sure if this is your problem, but I did get that exact same error message. Good luck.